# Wix and Windows Service questions

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services, wix

I have a Windows Service project that contains a WCF(selfhost) service (couple of dll files and a app.config), this is to be insalled with Wix.

I have added a reference to my Wix setup package and this is how the Product.wxs file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="MyAppINSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp 5Service">
        <Component Id="SampleServiceComponent" DiskId="1" Guid="6f51c0f3-776c-4aec-a200-1f199352c6c3" Win64="yes">
          <File Id="MyApp.WindowsService.exe" Name="MyApp.WindowsService.exe" Source="$(var.MyApp .WindowsService.TargetDir)\MyApp.WindowsService.exe"/>
          <ServiceInstall Id="InstallMyAppService" DisplayName="MyAppService" Name="MyApp .WindowsService.exe" Description="MyApp 5 Service - För effektivare och enklare operationsplanering" Account="NetworkService" ErrorControl="normal" Start="demand" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" />
          <ServiceControl Id="ControlMyAppService" Name="MyApp5.WindowsService.exe" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" />
        </Component>
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="MyAppINSTALLDIR" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Wix_MyApp.WindowsService" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="SampleServiceComponent" />
</Feature>
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="SampleServiceComponent.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
</Product>
```

And this work to a point and now I got some questions :

1. Right now it is only including my main Windows Service exe file? I need it to include all the output of my Selfhost
2. I need to be able to set the app.config of the Windows Service project before installining(It decides the name of the installed service), is it possible to use no compression and set file before running setup or is it easier to take information during installation and set it to app.config?

Edit 1:

To get all the files from the output I changed to this but it does not work? :

```
      <File Id="MyApp.WindowsService.Output"
        Name="$(var.MyApp.WindowsService.TargetFileName)"
        Source="$(var.MyApp.WindowsService.TargetPath)"
        KeyPath="yes" />

      <ServiceInstall Id="InstallMyAppService" DisplayName="MyAppService" Name="MyApp.WindowsService.exe" Description="MyApp 5 Service - För effektivare och enklare operationsplanering" Account="NetworkService" ErrorControl="normal" Start="demand" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" />
      <ServiceControl Id="ControlMyAppService" Name="MyApp.WindowsService.exe" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" />


    </Component>
```

Comment: What version of WiX are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To add another file to your installer, just add a new `<Component>` to your installer and put the `<File>` inside it. You'll also need to put the `<ComponentRef>` to that component in the `<Feature>`.
2. You can use `<XmlConfig>` or `<XmlFile>` elements to modify your app.config during your installation.

Comment: Thanks, See my Edit1, could I not just add all the files from the output in a similar way or do I have to add one and one?

Comment: A <File> element is for a single file. You will have to add them one by one. WiX also comes with a tool Heat, which you can use to harvest a bunch of files and generate the appropriate WiX source code, you generally have to massage the source code after running Heat to get it to work appropriately. I'd recommend adding them one by one.

Comment: So my Edit1 will not add all the files from the output? I read that Heat is disabled in 3.6 and will not be activated until 4.0

Comment: Correct, it will not add all the files. Also, you can still run Heat from command line or write some custom wrapper that runs Heat and cleans up the source code. You just can't run it on a Visual Studio project like before. You can run it on, say, a directory of files.